# eOne Dimensional Array with string input on java. Do not know how to make the array stop taking input until the user enters "alldone"

Tags: java, arrays, n-dimensional

I am suppose to make a one dimensional array until the user enters "alldone", however i dont know how to make it . This what i have and i know it is wrong .

The instruction are "Design a solution that requests and receives student names and an exam score for each. Use one-dimensional arrays to solve this.

The program should continue to accept names and scores until the user inputs a student whose name is “alldone”.
After the inputs are complete determine which student has the highest score and display that student’s name and score.
Finally sort the list of names and corresponding scores in ascending order."

Code so far:

```
String name = "";
    String highName = "";
    int highScore = 0;
    while (name != "alldone") {
        System.out.println("Enter name of student");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter grade of student.");
        int score = input.nextInt();
        if (name != "alldone" && score > highScore)
            highName = name;
        highScore = score;
        // System.out.println("Enter name"); name = input.nextLine(); }
        // System.out.println(highName + " had the highest score which was "
        // + highScore);
    }
```

now i have done this

```
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     int size= 1;

     String[] studentNames= new String[size];

     System.out.println("Enter name of student");
     String input = in.nextLine();
     String name = input;

     if (!name.equals("alldone")) {
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
             studentNames[i]= in.nextLine();
      } 
     else return;
     for (int k = 0; k<studentNames.length; k++) {
         System.out.println(studentNames[k] + " "); //so it can display names
```

Comment: Can you share some code with us?  Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service, contrary to what you may have heard from other people.

Comment: Please post some code written by you.

Comment: sorry i am new to coding and i thought i pasted it on to here

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include your code.

Comment: Please move this from comments to the actual question.

Comment: Also, explain what problem you're having. *i know it is wrong* isn't a helpful problem description.

Comment: My problem is that i do not know how to make the array until the word is typed "all done" is typed. I know how to sort and i know how to make it find the high score and student with the high score. @shmosel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Delete your question (it isn't useful for any future reader) and then read: [How do I compare strings in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/513832) and [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](//stackoverflow.com/q/13102045).

Comment: If that makes you feel any better, using simple array to do this is mostly stupid since you don't have any upper limit on the amount of students you can get. Aaand you might also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays#t=201701240326597642234

Comment: @ja1996 Again, include any relevant information in your post. They'll get lost in the comments.

Comment: Yeah, Tom's link will fix one of your issues.  Also, using !name.equals("alldone") rather than name != "alldone" will fix your original issue you asked about.

Comment: would i do a for loop after that to begin adding names @NickZiebert

Answer (score 1):

you should use this instead:

```
        if (!name.equals("alldone"))
```

Comment: Im sorry for the dumb question but after that would i make a For Loop to let the user enter names? or what would i do ?

Comment: Na, what you had at first is almost there.

Comment: im sorry i meant to ask  , how will i start the array , i have put 

         System.out.print("Enter " + studentName.length + " values: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < studentName.length; i++) 
      studentName[i] = input.nextLine();

Comment: no, no for loop is needed.  You need some sort of function like listofNames.add(name).  I give you hint, use arraylist, not array.  Google how to make arraylist.

Comment: we havent gone into array list yet so i am only allowed to use array.

Comment: Ah, ok.  This is what you need to do.  First off, even though it's a number, you need to do String score = input.nextLine().  Then, create a String array of size 2 and put your name in the first position and score in second position.  And then do that if test that you have above, grabbing the second element of that array.  Google how to do that.

Comment: im sorry to be annoying, however, i have to use one-dimensional array. Its due in a couple hours  so im trying to figure it as best as i can

Comment: Your not being annoying.  String[] myArray = new String[2] is a one dimensional array with 2 elements.  I have no idea why your teacher felt the need to specify "one dimensional", it's sort of implied.

Comment: yea, i got lost there, im a newbie to the coding world, im a visual learner, however its hard to understand. Ive changed my code and it still doesnt loop so i can enter another name into the array.

Comment: Alright, update your code above, lets see what you tried.

Comment: Thats as far ive gotten and nothing seems correct. Its really stressful

Comment: I think your teacher is trolling you.  This is a pretty complicated assignment when you are confined to only using single dimension arrays.  I'm trying to figure out how this is actually posisible.  You have to sort the list?  What list?

Comment: Have you studied classes?  The only way you can solve this is by creating a student class.  I've been assuming not if you are still on arrays.

Comment: he may be. i am not sure. but i have to get the assignment done, could you show me how the arraylist works

Comment: I really can't.  Just give him what you have.  I'd be interested to know if anybody in your class was able to complete this assignment without using classes.

Comment: well im doing it with setting the array to a fixed sized by asking the user "how many students will you enter " and than using that number to set the size